# Can I compare hprof/jmap dumps with VisualVM?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, hprof

VisualVM crashes when I try to profile our application with it, but if I could load the jmap memory dumps I've done from our application into VisualVM, I could probably get the answers I need without having to attach VisualVM to our app while it is running.

So, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Open VisualVM, click `File -> Load..` and pick your jmap file.

If it is not loaded, I guess there is a problem with your file.

Comment: I think this should be the accepter answer since the user specifically asked about visualvm. 
A bit embarrassed to admit that I didn't try this option, thought it should be loaded through "Add VM Coredump..." option. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

MAT ( [http://www.eclipse.org/mat/](http://www.eclipse.org/mat) ) is useful for comparing jmap/hprof files.  Try the dominator tree if you have a memory leak.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. MAT is _the_ tool for memory dump analysis on Java.